# IN JAVA Retrieving attachment content from EWS FileAttachment using EmailMessage is getting Null

Tags: java, api, exchangewebservices

We are creating Email message object using a file (`java.io.File`, the file has an `.eml` extension). But after creating email message, the `FileAttachment` class from `EmailMessage` object, is returning `null` for the content. Other attributes of `FileAttachment` seem fine like content name, content type.

Here is the code :

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), 
    new PropertySet( BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
    ItemSchema.MimeContent, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments ) );

for( Attachment attachment:message.getAttachments()) {
    FileAttachment attachment=(FileAttachment) attachment;
    attachment.getName();
    attachment.getContent();
}
```

The `getName()` call is fine, but `getContent()` returns null.

Comment: Legibility, code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.load()` on the FileAttachment first.

Comment: We called attachment.load() method but we are getting below error :               microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequest
Exception: The request failed. Precondition for readText is nextEvent().getTypeE
ventType() == START_ELEMENT
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequest at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequest
Base.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)  at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseService
Request.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequ

Comment: @DeepakJain Did you manage to get resolution? I am facing same problem.